# Hosted Agents do not conform to CIS Hardening Benchmarks

Tags: azure-devops

In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#security,there is a clear statement that Hosted Agents do not conform to CIS Hardening Benchmarks. What is it specifically about the agents that do not conform? Is there a particular reason for this, such as loss of some capability?

Answer (score 0):

Your mentioned doc: [Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#security), which states that Microsoft-hosted agents run on secure Azure platform. However, it mentions the security consideration: `Hosted images do not conform to CIS hardening benchmarks`.

If you want to get the detailed information (like particular reason) about this, we suggest that you submit this feedback [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) to contact the product group for further investigation.